# insert data into sqlclient in vb

Tags: database, vb.net, sqlclient

i need help. i try to add data into database using below coding. but the data can't save into the database. it's mean nothing happen in database after i click the 'SAVE' button

please check my coding. tq

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Public Class frmAddNewStaffAdmin

 Dim con As SqlClient.SqlConnection
 Dim dbSource As String
 Dim cmd As SqlClient.SqlCommand

 Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Try
        If Len(Trim(cboRole.Text)) = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please select user type", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            cboRole.Focus()
            Return
        ElseIf Len(Trim(txtStaffID.Text)) = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter Staff ID", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            txtStaffID.Focus()
            Return
        ElseIf Len(Trim(txtStaffName.Text)) = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter Staff Name", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            txtStaffName.Focus()
            Return
        ElseIf Len(Trim(txtUsername.Text)) = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter Username", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            txtUsername.Focus()
            Return
        ElseIf Len(Trim(txtPassword.Text)) = 0 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Please enter Password", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
            txtPassword.Focus()
            Return

        End If

        dbSource = "Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\HMS.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"

        con = New SqlConnection(dbSource)

        con.Open()

        Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO [User] (Staff_ID, Staff_Role, Staff_Name, Username, Password) VALUES ('" & txtStaffID.Text & "', '" & cboRole.Text & "', '" & txtStaffName.Text & "', '" & txtUsername.Text & "', '" & txtPassword.Text & "' ) "

        cmd = New SqlCommand(sql)

        cmd.Connection = con

        cmd.ExecuteReader()

        MessageBox.Show("Successfully saved", "Record", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

        con.Close()



    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    End Try

 End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery` and please look into SQl Injection and how to prevent it.

Comment: sorry your solution can't solved my problem. i don't know why

Comment: tq because edit my previous coding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two errors in your code

Change

```
Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO [User] (Staff_ID, Staff_Role, Staff_Name, Username, Password) VALUES ('" & txtStaffID.Text & "', '" & cboRole.Text & "', '" & txtStaffName.Text & "', '" & txtUsername.Text & "', '" & txtPassword.Text & "' ) "
```

to

```
Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO [User] (Staff_ID, Staff_Role, Staff_Name, Username, [Password]) VALUES ('" & txtStaffID.Text & "', '" & cboRole.Text & "', '" & txtStaffName.Text & "', '" & txtUsername.Text & "', '" & txtPassword.Text & "' ) "
```

Edit:

Use the Query like this

```
    Dim sql As String = "INSERT INTO [User] (Staff_ID, Staff_Role, Staff_Name, Username, [Password]) VALUES (@StaffID,@Role,@StaffName,@Username,@Password) "

   Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Staff_ID", txtStaffID.Text)
   Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Role", cboRole.Text)
   Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StaffName", txtStaffName.Text)
   Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", txtUsername.Text )
   Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", txtPassword.Text)
```

1. Changes made `Password` to `[Password]` because `Password` is a reserved keyword.
2. Change `cmd.ExecuteReader()` to `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()`

## Difference between `ExecuteNonQuery` and `ExecuteReader`

**ExecuteNonQuery**

> ExecuteNonQuery method will return number of rows effected with
>   INSERT, DELETE or UPDATE operations. This ExecuteNonQuery method will
>   be used only for insert, update and delete, Create, and SET
>   statements. [(Read More about ExecuteNonQuery)](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/09/executenonquery-example-in-aspnet-using.html)

[SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**ExecuteReader**

> Execute Reader will be used to return the set of rows, on execution of
>   SQL Query or Stored procedure using command object. This one is
>   forward only retrieval of records and it is used to read the table
>   values from first to last.[(Read More about ExecuteReader)](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/09/sqlcommand-executereader-example-in.html)

[SqlCommand.ExecuteReader MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executereader%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: sorry your solution can't solved my problem. i don't know why

Comment: @user3413582 Do you get any errors while compiling??

Comment: Can you keep breakpoint and check step by step and say the exact error??

Comment: after i do breakpoint from con.open until con.close, only con. open display the yellow color. others display red color. what is mean?

Comment: actually i don't how to check error using breakpoint. sorry, i'm a beginner

Comment: take screenshot of it and post it..!!

Comment: i can't post the screenshot here.

Comment: to help we need the screenshot

Comment: this a link to view the table schema https://www.dropbox.com/s/1tio9pe0e98f3o5/table%20schema.png can u view it?

Comment: I need it with the datatype, there may be issue with the datatype

Comment: one more thing, when i run the program with the breakpoint i saw the value for dbsource, sql, cmd and cmd.connection is "nothing". what is mean?

Comment: are you passing all the value in the text box as you have declared there should be no null values you should pass all values in the textbox

Comment: this is what i get when i run the project using breakpoint https://www.dropbox.com/s/dfjiwh6ndgaat8c/error.png

Comment: see at the line you will get nothing when the next step is processed you will get the value in it..!! check the dbsource value when the execution is in con = new sqlconnection(dbsource) . You will see the connection string in it

Comment: cmd = New SqlCommand(sql)  cmd.connection = con Move both the lines and place it after this line Dim Sql as string

Comment: To check by line by line press `F11`

Comment: may i know, actually what the problem?

Comment: @user3413582 to find out the problem i'm saying to do the step by step process

Comment: i can save the data now.but why the data can display in db?

Comment: If the data is saved you can view it in your database table.

Comment: i change the database. before i use local server inside VS, is not working. but after i change to MS server 200 r2, it's work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()` not `cmd.ExecuteReader()`

Comment: sorry your solution can't solved my problem. i don't know why